# Streching UV on corners

Tags: uv, edges

[image]Hello, I am a beginner in Blender. I am trying to create a couch. As you see in picture, UV grid streches on round edges. So I tried these methods,

- Selected sharp edges and marked as seams.
- Selected Keep corners option on subdivison surface modifier.
- Tried edge crease but lost rounded shape geometry.

So I want to keep rounded geometry on couch and if it's possible do not want to add more geometry.

Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello, I attached the file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to using the subdivision modifier is to bevel the edges of the cushion and armrest.

Start by cleaning up the mesh:

1. Delete the Subdivision modifier.
2. **Edit mode** > with all selected > **Mesh** > **Clean Up** > **Limited Dissolve**
3. Remove existing UV seams : with all selected > **U** > **Clear Seam**.

Next bevel the edges:

4. With all selected > **Ctrl B**, to open the Bevel parameters and change the bevel **Width** value as needed and set the **Segments** to **4**. (An even number will result in correct corner edges which will be needed when marking UV seams).

Now we are ready to add back the UV seams:
Where we add UV seams can vary depending how you want the texture to be mapped to the mesh. In this example we want the top and side to unwrap as a single UV island and so we add seams along each corner and along the the edges of the bottom face. See gif anim. below.

5. Select the appropriate edges the **U** > **Mark Seams**.

[image]

And Finally the faces can be set to smooth shading:

6. Edit mode with all selected > **Face** > **Shade Smooth**.

If necessary the UV's can now be edited to suit the alignment of the texture and or rescaled for example for baking so that the visible faces of the mesh occupy more of the UV space :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response and detailed explanation. That is worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable the *On Cage* option of the *Subdivision Surface* you'll see the position of the seam edge as modified by the modifier:

[image]

To fix the problem you'll need to add 2 support edge loops, but of course you'll loose the round corners, you'll have to change your topology if you want to keep them:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. If I didn't misunderstand, it's not possible to get a rounded shape result without adding new geometry right?

Comment: I don't think so, don't only count on the subdivision surface to create a round shape

Comment: Thank you so much again. That's a new thing to keep in my mind.